# How to make a popup disappear only when clicked anywhere outside of it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, popup

I'm trying to toggle a popup when click on a specific link and then remove class ".open" from it when clicked anywhere other than the popup box.

Using below methods I was able to get the popup disappear when clicked outside of it but it's now also getting disappear when clicked inside the popup area.

```js
    $(".onclick-dropdown-link, .user-message-center-link").on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        var $this = $(this);
        var id = $this.attr('href');
        $('.onclick-dropdown').not(id).removeClass('open');
        $(id).toggleClass('open');        
    });
        $('body:not(.onclick-dropdown.open)').click(function(e) {
            $("#alert-center, #message-center, #user-message-center").removeClass('open');
        });
```

```css
    .onclick-dropdown {
        opacity: 0;
        visibility: hidden;
        background: #f3f3f3;
        width: 390px;
        height: 390px;
        position: absolute;
        top: 128px;
        right: 28px;
        height: auto;
        padding: 0;
        z-index: 999;
    }
    .onclick-dropdown.open {
        opacity: 1;
        visibility: visible;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li class="alert-center-link">
        <a class="onclick-dropdown-link" href="#alert-center">The Link</a>
    </li>
</ul>
<div id="alert-center" class="onclick-dropdown">
  <p>Lorem Ipusm</p>
</div>
```

Comment: the logic as I see it would be to catch click on the document, and check if the element clicked is a descendant of the popup or not

Answer (score 0):

Change your `.click()` function to the following:

```
$(document).click(function(e) {
  if( !$('.onclick-dropdown').is(e.target) && !$('.onclick-dropdown').children().is(e.target)) {
   if( $('.onclick-dropdown').hasClass('open') ) {
      $("#alert-center, #message-center, #user-message-center").removeClass('open');
      }
   }
});
```

Comment: Sorry but your code didn't work when I clicked on elements inside the popup area.

Comment: You never said you needed to click anything inside the popup area.

Answer (score 0):

```
// only trigger once
$('body').one('click', function(e) {
  var $target = $(e.target);

  // the $target which trigger click event is not the popup dom itself
  // and also is not the children dom of the popup
  if (!$target.is('#alert-center') && $target.parents('#alert-center').length === 0) {
    $("#alert-center, #message-center, #user-message-center").removeClass('open');
  }
})
```

Is that what you want?
Now you can add any tags in the popup, and click inside the popup area where not hide it.

Comment: Your code worked perfectly after I changed the first line to -

`$('body').on('click', function(e) {`

Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Beware and check it in all browsers. Events doesn't bubble correctly in every browser.

Comment: Yes, please test carefully for browser compatibility.And I use `one('click,function(){}')` because I think you don't want to bind this event on body forever.Sorry that I use wrong API before.

Answer (score 0):

Change your Popup HTML to :

```
<div id="alert-center-outer" class="onclick-dropdown">
  <div id="alert-center">
    //CONTENT HERE...
    <p>Lorem Ipusm</p>
  </div>
</div>

#alert-center-outer{
  position: fixed;
  left; 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0.5;
  background-color: black;
}
#alert-center{
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;/*This will center align it.*/
}
```

Clicking the #alert-center-outer should hide the popup.

Clicking the #alert-center should stopPropagation so that it doesn't bubble to its parent.

Answer (score 0):

try below code

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".onclick-dropdown-link, .user-message-center-link").on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    var $this = $(this);
    var id = $this.attr('href');
    $('.onclick-dropdown').not(id).removeClass('open');
    $(id).toggleClass('open');        
});
    $(document).click(function(e) { 
    if (!$(e.target).closest('.onclick-dropdown').length)
     
               $("#alert-center, #message-center, #user-message-center").removeClass('open');
    });
})
```

```css
.onclick-dropdown {
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    background: #f3f3f3;
    width: 390px;
    height: 390px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 128px;
    right: 28px;
    height: auto;
    padding: 0;
    z-index: 999;
}
.onclick-dropdown.open {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <div id="alert-center" class="onclick-dropdown">
            <p>Lorem Ipusm</p>
        </div>
        
         <li class="alert-center-link"><a class="onclick-dropdown-link" href="#alert-center">asdfsdfsdfds</a></li>
```